# Sidekiq with Heroku & Rails : my Jobs are stucks in queue on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

**Solution EDIT :**

The worker button on Heroku was not turned from Off to On...

---

I'm trying to use Sidekiq on my RailsApp. The configuration works fine in development but in Product with Heroku, all Jobs are enqued but stuck in queue.

**Some insight :**

I've done the config of Redis_to_go on Heroku.

Sidekiq dashboard 
[image]

**Heroku Job logs**

```
2018-11-09T17:28:15.648569+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-11-09T17:28:15.648360 #4]  INFO -- : [66d0e53c-5fd1-42a9-bb28-4df4a40b6f09] 

[ActiveJob] Enqueued CreateMemberContactJob (Job ID: 12785f83-5b69-4bc4-ad87-3945694e8337) 

to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000055ec32248780 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://youguildapp/Member/85>>
```

All my configuration & code :
**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

**Application.rb**

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

**Registrationscontroller.rb**

```
CreateMemberContactJob.perform_later @member
```

class CreateMemberContactJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

**CreateMemberContactJob**

```
class CreateMemberContactJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(member)
    api_instance = SibApiV3Sdk::ContactsApi.new
    create_contact = SibApiV3Sdk::CreateContact.new
    create_contact.email = member.email

    api_instance.create_contact(create_contact)
  end

end
```

Please help me, I've passed by all SO posts & Sidekiq wifi & Medium posts & holy books but I didn't figured out.

Many thanks

Comment: Stupid assumption, but check if your sidekiq worker is turned on on Heroku, it is off by default

Comment: That is likely the answer: you haven't actually started a Sidekiq worker dyno.

Comment: @Vasilisa & Mike, you found the solution : it was the button... Many thanks! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

### This is how you turn the heroku worker dyno button on:

[image: How one turns on the heroku dyno?]